# Error when converting a date from a form to sql.date format

Tags: java, sql, forms, jsp, date

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd");
String sbd=request.getParameter("begindate");
java.util.Date bd2=df.parse(sbd);
java.sql.Date bd = new java.sql.Date(bd2.getTime());
```

I am trying to send data from a form to a JSP page and insert it in an SQL database, but I'm having problems with the date format. yyyy-MM-dd is the default format for my dates, but still I get an exception in the following line when executing the code:

```
java.util.Date bd2=df.parse(sbd);
```

I have looked at similar questions and tried changing a few things, but I can't seem to find what's the real issue.

Edit: Here's the stacktrace

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

Update:

When removing the apostrophes the exception remains, but the exception message changes:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: What format does the Strong sbd have?

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the format that you initialize df with to "yyyy-MM-dd" without the apostrophes surrounding the hyphens.

Comment: I did it already (it was my first attempt), but the result was the same. I have tried again and there's still an exception but the stacktrace changes (I'll update the question)

Comment: Have you tried printing the contents of sbd before attempting to parse the string into a Date object? If not, I would suggest you do this and make sure that you actually got a string out of the request parameter, as the second stacktrace would indicate the value of either sbd or df is null. If sbd is a well formed string in the "yyyy-MM-dd" format you want, then I would perform a null test on df. Also, if the exception string that begins the stacktrace is different in the first error (not a null exception) can you add that as well?

Answer (score 0):

In JSP, you should use [JSTL fmt tag library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) that provides a set of tags for parsing and formatting locale-sensitive numbers and dates and try to avoid Scriplet.

Read more [Oracle Tutorial - Internationalization Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL6.html) and [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/)

Sample code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

<c:set value="2014-10-23" var="dateString" />

<fmt:parseDate value="${dateString}" var="dateObject" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />

<fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

*Note:* The format completely depends on the data string.

---

You can use `${param.begindate}` to get the `begindate` from request parameter using `param` implicit object in jsp.

Sample code:

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${param.begindate}" var="dateObject" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
```

---

To avoid `NullPointerException` you should first check it.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.begindate}">
      ...
</c:if>
```